# Report Builder 1.0 recommended system requirements

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I can't seem to find this on MSDN but can anyone tell me the recommended system requirements for running Report Builder 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN:

The client computer must have the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 installed. The .NET Framework provides the infrastructure for running ClickOnce applications.

You must use Microsoft Internet Explorer 6.0 or later.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365173(v=SQL.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365173%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)